# How do I format a string?

Tags: c#, string, date

I have a string "5-13-2013"
I want to make it look like "051313"
All three fields (month,day,year) must have 2 digits, if it only has one , I need to add a zero in front

any easy way to do this?

Comment: What programming language do you want to do this in?

Comment: sorry should have mentioned I'm using c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your datetime to multiple formats like

```
string date = yourdateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
string date = yourdateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm");
string date = yourdateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
string date = yourdateTime.ToString("mmddyy"); // your desired
```

To know what these mean you need to read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: you mean mmddyy, not yyyy.